# usb_cam: [ERROR]Webcam: expected picture but didn't get it

Tags: ros, usb-cam, camera, webcam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to use

```
rosrun usb_cam usb_cam_node
```

to read my web camera, but it keeps returning error:

> [ERROR] [1392890872.217213339]: Webcam: expected picture but didn't get it...

> [ERROR] [1392890872.252854641]: Webcam: expected picture but didn't get it...

> [ERROR] [1392890872.285282152]: Webcam: expected picture but didn't get it...

> [ERROR] [1392890872.317282039]: Webcam: expected picture but didn't get it...

[ERROR] [1392890872.352863707]: Webcam: expected picture but didn't get it...

> 

[ERROR] [1392890872.385424928]: Webcam: expected picture but didn't get it...

> 

[ERROR] [1392890872.421215144]: Webcam: expected picture but didn't get it...

> 

[ERROR] [1392890872.453295782]: Webcam: expected picture but didn't get it...

> 

[ERROR] [1392890872.485294812]: Webcam: expected picture but didn't get it...

> 

[ERROR] [1392890872.521231924]: Webcam: expected picture but didn't get it...

> 

[ERROR] [1392890872.553230292]: Webcam: expected picture but didn't get it...

> 

...

The camera works well when using

```
guvcview
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/131331/usb_cam:-%5Berror%5Dwebcam:-expected-picture-but-didn%27t-get-it.../) by [lanyusea](https://answers.ros.org/users/10266/lanyusea/) on ROS Answers with karma: 279 on 2014-02-19

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [4LV4R0](https://answers.ros.org/users/7366/4lv4r0/) on 2014-02-19**:
I have the same errors. I guess it depends on pixel_format because if I do "rosparam set usb_cam/pixel_format yuyv" and then "rosrun usb_cam usb_cam_node" I get a constant amount of frames/sec with no errors but after that I can´t see the image well: Maybe a codification problem.

**Comment by [lanyusea](https://answers.ros.org/users/10266/lanyusea/) on 2014-02-19**:
@4LV4R0 yes. thanks for your advice, it is a format problem.  Not quite sure about the frame rate problem, my image_view node works well on Ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved that problem.

I need to use

```
rosparam set usb_cam/pixel_format yuyv
```

before

```
rosrun usb_cam usb_cam_node
```

The problem should be the color format.

Before:

> [ INFO] [1392893303.485168904]: usb_cam pixel_format set to [mjpeg]

After:

> [ INFO] [1392893336.088686109]: usb_cam pixel_format set to [yuyv]

Then I can see the video stream using
`rosrun image_view image_view image:=/usb_cam/image_raw`

---

Originally posted by [lanyusea](https://answers.ros.org/users/10266/lanyusea/) with karma: 279 on 2014-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2015-11-30**:
Or `rosrun usb_cam usb_cam_node pixel_format:=yuyv`

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi i had a problem like this when i want to use roslaunch usb_cam-test.launch , so i did these :
1.rosdep update
2.sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-image-pipeline
3.rosdep install camera_calibration
so after that exchange mjpeg with yuyv in launch file and then run : roslaunch usb_cam-test.launch
now you should see your image
goodluck

---

Originally posted by [fatima](https://answers.ros.org/users/23862/fatima/) with karma: 62 on 2015-11-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1